# AJAX Delete Table Row without re-loading page after Successful Delete from Database

Tags: php, ajax, row

I have a table that is populate using AJAX.  Each table row is give an id based on a record id in my database. Under the table are 3 buttons: NEW, EDIT and DELETE.

When I select a row I set the data-id of the DELETE button to the clicked row's ID.  When I click DELETE my AJAX call proceeds to delete all records from my database that have the data-id of the DELETE button.

This all works perfectly. After everything is done i get an alert the the data was deleted.  Which is great.

My Question is: in the If (data ==1) section of my AJAX call, how do i remove the row, fade out, from the table without refreshing the page like i have to do now.

Here is my index.html code

```html
<div class="container-fluid inputwrapper">
    <table id="workRequests" style="width: 100%;">
       //table is filled by ajax call to db below is an example of the format
       <tr class="table__row" id="124108" onclick="highlight_row()">
          <td class="table__content" data-heading="Number">124108</td>
          ....
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row center-block">
<div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-0" style="float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="text-center col-sm-8" style="float: left;">
<button style="margin-right: 10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="wopnew" onClick="createNew()">New</button>
<button style="margin-right: 10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled id="wopedit" onClick="editFile()">Edit</button>
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-id="0"  id="wopdelete">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-0" style="float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Here is my AJAX call.
I am a novice at coding and from what I can see as i Step thought the function in my browser - the var element is set to the DELETE button data-id so when we get to the success part and data == 1 nothing happens as it is focused on the DELETE button not the Table Row.

I have tried to change element to the id of my table but that does not work either.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click","#wopdelete",function(){  
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?  It can NOT be recoverd!!")) { 
        
        var id = $(this).data('id');  
        var element = this;  
        $.ajax({  
            url :"./scripts/delRecord.php",  
            type:"POST",  
            cache:false,  
            data:{deleteId:id},  
            success:function(data){  
                if (data == 1) {  
                    $(element).closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                     
                    alert("User record deleted successfully");       
                }else{  
                    alert("Record did not delete properly!");  
                }  
            } 
        });  
    }  
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Try with `var element = $(this).closest('tr');`,  then in the success: `element.fadeOut(400...` in the fadeOut hander function: `element.remove();`.

Comment: Also, instead of searching it with `closest`, you can remove it by its `id="124108"`. I assume it *should* be unique on the whole page.

Comment: @biesior's suggestion is good too. I didn't pay attention to the row's `id`, I was thinking more about the button's potential id.

Comment: However, I'd modify it a little bit to make it even more unique, like i.e. `workrequest_124108` otherwise you risk that someday you'll clash with another `124108` id which would be i.e. `comment_124108`. Of course, that's not in your code, but sometimes it's good to *think forward`.

Comment: Paul -> I tried as you have suggested, $(this).closest('tr');  but "this" still references the "DELETE" button.

Comment: the ID will always be unique as it is an auto increment from my db.